# CSS overflow: auto is not working on table or tbody

Tags: html, css, asp.net

http://jsfiddle.net/buL4y6w9/1/

Above is the jsFiddle that has a lot of messy looking code in it.

Some properties of CSS are obviously being overwritten by other properties, and I can't tell (using **Chrome**'s *Developer Tools*) what is causing it.

My actual HTML is in a **Visual Studio** *ASP.NET Master Page*. I would post it, but there is no data included in that.

```
<div id="datagrids">
 <asp:DataGrid ID="RollupDG" OnItemDataBound="DataGridYear_ItemDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="True" />
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowGLdetail" runat="server" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="All" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "acctRollupName") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Jan" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth1" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_01", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Feb" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth2" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_02", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Mar" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth3" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="3" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_03", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Apr" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth4" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="4" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_04", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="May" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth5" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="5" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_05", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Jun" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth6" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="6" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_06", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Jul" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth7" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="7" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_07", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Aug" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth8" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="8" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_08", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sep" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth9" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="9" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_09", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Oct" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth10" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="10" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_10", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Nov" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth11" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="11" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_11", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Dec" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMonth12" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="12" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "db_amount_12", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="annualBudget" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Budget" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="YTD" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="YTD" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Annualized" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Annualized" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="OverUnder" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Variance" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="acctRollupName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="accountCategory" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
  </Columns>
  <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DataGrid>
<!-- Datagrid containing quarterly GL data -->
<b><asp:Label ID="LabelAccount" runat="server" /></b>
<asp:DataGrid ID="QuarterDG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemDataBound="DataGridQuarter_ItemDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="True" />
    <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowGLdetail" runat="server" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="All" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "acctRollupName") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Q1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowQ1" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="Q1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Q1", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Q2" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowQ2" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="Q2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Q2", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Q3" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowQ3" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="Q3" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Q3", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Q4" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowQ4" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:C}" OnCommand="catGLdetail" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "account") %>' CommandName="Q4" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Q4", "{0:C0}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="annualBudget" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Budget" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="YTD" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="YTD" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Annualized" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Annualized" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="OverUnder" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" HeaderText="Variance" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="acctRollupName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="accountCategory" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" />
  </Columns>
  <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DataGrid>
<asp:Label ID="DetailSecurityNote" runat="server" Text="Note: This list contains only those transactions to which you are authorized." Visible="false" /><br />
<br />
<!-- Table container for detail GL filter like Excel autofilter -->
<table id="LawsonFilter" runat="server" style="border:1px solid; padding:0px; width:950px;">
  <tr id="row1" runat="server">
    <td id="cell1" runat="server" width="150" align="middle">
      Date: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDate" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LawsonFilterEvent" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td id="cell2" runat="server" width="150" align="middle">
      Code: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCode" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LawsonFilterEvent" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td id="cell3" runat="server" width="400" align="middle">
      Vendor: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LawsonFilterEvent" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Datagrid containing detail GL data -->
<asp:DataGrid ID="glDetailDG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="950px" AllowSorting="True" OnSortCommand="LawsonSortEvent" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="transdate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" SortExpression="transdate" HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="GLaccount" SortExpression="GLaccount" HeaderText="Account" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="accountDesc" SortExpression="GLaccount" HeaderText="Desc" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="company" SortExpression="company" HeaderText="Vendor" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Invoice" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="btnShowInvoice" NavigateUrl='<%# "Default.aspx?apinvoice="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "apinvoice")+"&vendornum="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "vendornum") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "apinvoice") %>' Target="_new" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="amount" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  </Columns>
  <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
 </asp:DataGrid>
</div>
```

Nothing above (that I can see) should cause my `<table>` to have the CSS Property **display:inline-block;** that *Developer Tools* is showing me.

[image: Developer Tools]

Instead, I just went to "View Source" and copied all of it in there except for the binary DLL.

My CSS skills are OK until items start having different types of `position` attributes or until certain HTML features have overlapping properties that cancel out what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone know how to get the table in the jsFiddle link at the top to have scroll bars? I have tried setting the **overflow:auto** in both the `<table>` and `<tbody>` controls. Developer Tools shows it there, too, but the HTML does not have it.

### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the: `overflow: auto;` in the containing div's css, not the table itself, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/puj64wrh/  (sorry for how crude it is).  You also have to define a fixed width and height in the container for the scrollbars to work.

Side note:

"My CSS skills are OK until items start having different types of position attributes or until certain HTML features have overlapping properties that cancel out what I'm trying to do."

You can always (I recommend limited usage) use "!important" with a value to override any other styling.  Here is an article on that:

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: I got it working in your example. When I added it to my code http://jsfiddle.net/buL4y6w9/3/, it does limit the width, but not the height ...and no scroll bar on the width.

Comment: I also had `!important` on a few of those settings, but they were obviously in the wrong place - they did no good.

Comment: Sorry, you have to also give it a fixed width and height, which you may want to use min- and max- variations.  Here is a quick example, and I will update my answer to include this information:

http://jsfiddle.net/buL4y6w9/4/

Comment: Your version works, but I can't seem to get it to work on my version. I see you added `html{ height:100%; }` along with the small **width** and **height** sections. Are small values for W & H required for this to work? I have to have it fill the display.

Comment: Ignore the HTML height.  A width and height are required.  They don't have to be small though.  I think you can ignore the HTML height --  I'm mobile now so I can't try it.